Android Emulator not getting created in android studio
I created a new project in android studio. When I tried to run the android app project in emulator, I am getting this error.

I have virtualization enabled in my laptop
Android studio version is
Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-241.18034.62.2411.12071903, built on July 11, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.11+0--11852314 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 12
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.jetbrains.kmm (0.8.3(241)-9)

I am not able to figure out the root cause of this issue.
please help
